# What's Special about Resist Pens?

Tags: prototyping, pcb-fabrication, etching

Just what is special about the resist pens used to draw directly on PCBs before etching?   Would a permanent marker work as well, or some other kind pen or marker?  Naturally I have in mind something cheaper but good enough.   This is for one-off handmade projects, single or double sided boards only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permanent marker will work but the finishing may not be that very great and you might want to give it a solder coat later. A resist pen just forms a thicker layer than a marker would do, giving it more isolation from etching chemical and a better finish.

I have used it couple of time If I am lazy for other long method where I get the circuit done on a PCB designer and get it printed on photo-paper etc. But for a good finish and a complex circuit I would suggest this method of etching is the best and reliable. I have been using it since years and never had a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly about how much ink they put down - certainly worth testing some standard permanent markers on some scrap material. Many shops that sell markers have testers you can try so maybe take a bit of copperclad with you & try a few.

Comment: They also don't have water soluble inks

Answer (score 2):

I used to get very good results with ordinary cellulose paint, applied with a fine paint brush. Thinning the paint a little with cellulose thinners helped if I needed narrow tracks. It worked better than the resist pens and was much cheaper.

Comment: I'm an artist too - perhaps acrylic paint will work?  There's no shortage of it at my house, and I have plenty of fine brushes.

Comment: It should be OK. Cellulose paint is probably easier to remove after etching.

Answer (score 1):

["pcbprt - Experiments in inkjet PCB printing"](http://www.pabr.org/pcbprt/pcbprt.en.html) by pascal. Some inkjet printers can print directly CD and DVD. They can print on copper-clad FR4 to make reasonably good etch resist. The main trick seems to be baking the freshly-printed boards to dry out the ink and get the dyes/pigments to stick to the copper -- otherwise the water-based ink immediately washes off as soon as you drop the board in the etch tank.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with *some* overhead-projector-transparency pens (remember OHPs? :).  The dark blue and brown Staedtlers worked best IIRC, the purple one not very well at all - remember to use the "permanent" ones, not the water-based ones.

A bit of trial and error is the order of the day!